# Simulation Bet Results using Matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

Consider the following Matrices and Variable ***INITIAL_WEALTH = 1000***

Each column is a simulation and each row is a step of the simulation:

***bet_pct_wealth*** (The Percentage of the Actual Wealth put on each bet)

```
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.0467 0.0700 0.0467 0.0467 0.0700
[2,] 0.0350 0.0700 0.0350 0.0467 0.0350
[3,] 0.0280 0.0467 0.0467 0.0467 0.0467
[4,] 0.1400 0.0700 0.0700 0.0700 0.0467
[5,] 0.0350 0.0467 0.0350 0.0700 0.0350
[6,] 0.0700 0.0700 0.0350 0.0700 0.0700
```

***bet_results*** (1 indicates that i won the bet 0 indicates i lost)

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

***bet_payoff*** (How much is the payoff in case i won in relation to the total bet)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    3    3    2
[2,]    4    2    4    3    4
[3,]    5    3    3    3    3
[4,]    1    2    2    2    3
[5,]    4    3    4    2    4
[6,]    2    2    4    2    2
```

What i am trying to do is to create another matrix thats shows on each step what is my actual wealth. So the simulation steps are the following :

1-) Initial Wealth = 1000 for every simulation so my first row of the resulting matrix would be :

***total_wealth***

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
```

2-) My first round bets would be

```
total_wealth[1,]*bet_pct_wealth[1,]
```

If i win the bet my total_wealth[2,] would be :

```
 total_wealth[1,] +  total_wealth[1,] * bet_pct_wealth[1,0] * bet_payoff[1,0]
```

and if i loose

```
 total_wealth[1,] -  total_wealth[1,]  * bet_pct_wealth[1,0]
```

then you repeat the simulation until you get (rounded by 2 decimals) :

```
        [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
[1,]    1000      1000     1000     1000      1000
[2,]    953,3     930      953,3    1140,1    1140
[3,]    919,93    864,9    1086,76  1299,83   1100,1
[4,]    1048,72   986,07   1239,02  1481,94   1048,73
[5,]    1195,54   1124,12  1152,29  1378,2    999,75
[6,]    1153,7    1071,62  1313,61  1281,73   964,76
[7,]    1072,94   996,61   1267,63  1192,01   897,23
```

Any ideias on how to use the 3 matrices to get the fourth one ? I was able to code this simulation without matrices as you can see here :

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/kelly-capital-growth-investment-strategy-example-in-r

But the results simulation is very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's great that you provided some example data and the results you expect to see.  You may find that you get better response if you provide code that folks can simply copy and paste to get your data.  For example,

```
bet_pct_wealth <- structure(c(0.0467, 0.035, 0.028, 0.14, 0.035, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
0.0467, 0.07, 0.0467, 0.07, 0.0467, 0.035, 0.0467, 0.07, 0.035, 
0.035, 0.0467, 0.0467, 0.0467, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.035, 
0.0467, 0.0467, 0.035, 0.07), .Dim = c(6L, 5L))

bet_results <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), .Dim = c(6L, 5L))

bet_payoff <- structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L), .Dim = c(6L, 5L))

initial_wealth <- rep(1000, 5)
```

Your problem can be simplified if you combine the win/loss result and the payoff into a single matrix that can be used in the same equation to calculate results.  Then, you can use the `cumprod()` function to calculate the cumulative products down the rows of your matrix.

```
# combine the win/loss and the pay off to get a combined result
bet_combined <- bet_results * bet_payoff
bet_combined[bet_combined==0] <- -1

multiplier <- 1 + bet_pct_wealth * bet_combined
apply(rbind(initial_wealth, multiplier), 2, cumprod)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will keep that in mind when posting future questions

Comment: yes a lot ! thank you very much, you can check the complete code here 
http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/kelly-capital-growth-investment-strategy-example-in-r

Comment: @vonjd I rebuilt the question, can you check if now you can run the code. I tried step by step as described now and works fine for me ....